# Laravel Excel chunk + noHeading not working together

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm working with large excel-files (~160k rows) which are loaded in with phpexcel using maatwesite-excel (laravel excel).

Although when using 'chunk' I can't access 'noHeading()'.

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($pricefile->real_path)->chunk(250, function($reader)    {
    $reader = $reader->noHeading(); //Error: Method noHeading does not exist.
}

Excel::load($pricefile->real_path, function($reader){ 
    $reader = $reader->noHeading(); //array(0 => 'value', [...])
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a "reader" when using "chunk". In the case of chunk, you are getting the results directly, which you would otherwise get from the reader using

```
$reader->get();
```

So you got the results in your function, which do not have a method called "noHeading()".

I don't know if the headers are included there by default.
You can get more details about chunks here:

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#chunk

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->noHeading()->load($path)->chunk(250, function($results)
{
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            // work in here               
        }
    });
```